# Processing two files at the same time, one in xls and the other in text formats

Tags: python, file, text, process

I have two files, one contains alarms which are generated by networking devices when there is a failure, which is in txt format. and the other file contains tickets which are generated by network administrator for dealing with these alarms, which is in xls format.several alarms may be associated to one ticket. There are two most important fields in both files which are creation time and Node ID.

1. I need to sort the alarms in ascending order according to the creation time filed
2. take The Node ID filed for all the tickets

   - Define a time window W = 2 days
3. For every ticket within this time window 
   Explore the alarms with node=Node ID in W

Results:

- Total amount of tickets in the study period.
- Amount of tickets with correlated alerts.
- Mean amount of alerts per correlated ticket.
- List of Node ID which have not been correlated with any alert.
- Total amount of alerts in the study period.
- Percentage of alerts that have been correlated to at least a ticket.

I hope I summarize my problem in obvious  way. I have tried several times but I am new to python and really I need your help.

Thank you very much in your

Comment: While it is somewhat clear what your source data is, and what your goal is... its not clear what your specific problem is. You say you tried several times. What did you try? What is not working? Give us something specific to address.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native facilities in Python for processing Microsoft Excel (xls) files. Of course processing the CSV file will be trivial, but it you can't get the XLS file into something more native, you're going to have to explore third party solutions.

This link might help http://www.python-excel.org/